# Database schema for end user report designer

Tags: sql-server, database-design, report, schema

I'm trying to implement a feature whereby, apart from all the reports that I have in my system, I will allow the end user to create simple reports. (not overly complex reports that involves slicing and dicing across multiple tables with lots of logic)

The user will be able to:

1) Select a base table from a list of allowable tables (e.g., Customers)

2) Select multiple sub tables (e.g., Address table, with AddressId as the field to link Customers to Address)

3) Select the fields from the tables

4) Have basic sorting

Here's the database schema I have current, and I'm quite certain it's far from perfect, so I'm wondering what else I can improve on

AllowableTables table

This table will contain the list of tables that the user can create their custom reports against.

```
Id      Table        
----------------------------------
1       Customers
2       Address
3       Orders
4       Products
```

ReportTemplates table

```
Id                     Name                     MainTable
------------------------------------------------------------------
1                      Customer Report #2       Customers
2                      Customer Report #3       Customers
```

ReportTemplateSettings table

```
Id   TemplateId  TableName   FieldName   ColumnHeader   ColumnWidth  Sequence  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1           Customer    Id          Customer S/N   100          1         
2    1           Customer    Name        Full Name      100          2         
3    1           Address     Address1    Address 1      100          3
```

I know this isn't complete, but this is what I've come up with so far. Does anyone have any links to a reference design, or have any inputs as to how I can improve this?

Comment: As a suggestion use the INFOMRATION_SCHEMA.table and columns views which already has this data rather then storing it again.

Comment: That returns me all the tables in my DB

Comment: Yes but you can join your table with the information_Schema.columns to store all the data about columns. No need to duplicate that.

Answer (score 0):

This needs a lot of work even though it’s relatively simple task. Here are several other columns you might want to include as well as some other details to take care of.

- Store table name along with schema name or store schema name in additional column, add column for sorting and sort order
- Create additional table to store child tables that will be used in the report (report id, schema name, table name, column in child table used to join tables, column in parent table used to join tables, join operator (may not be needed if it always =)
- Create additional table that will store column names (report id, schema name, table name, column name, display as)

There are probably several more things that will come up after you complete this but hopefully this will get you in the right direction.